# remove every other field from a table

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I have a table call tom, it has 6000 entries in a field called fred, how can I remove every other field?

eg

1 2 3 4 5 6 7

so I end up with 1 3 5 7 etc

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use modulo arithmetic:

```
delete t from tom t
    where mod(fred, 2) = 1;
```

Comment: it didnt work. did you mean? delete tom from table tom
    where mod(fred, 2) = 1;

Comment: I just need to delete every other field in a table called tom. I have 6000 fields so I will end up with 3000 fields. thanks